# Order of use of "rife"

Tags: adjectives

Is there an order in which sentences with the adjective "rife" should be constructed? For example, searching for "rife" in Google gives the following example under the definition:

> "male chauvinism was rife in medicine" [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=rife)

Can the sentence be turned around to the following form?

> "Medicine was rife with male chauvinism"

Are the two meanings equivalent? Are they exactly the same? Is one favoured over the other?

In general, are "*x* is rife with *y*" and "*y* is rife in *x*" equivalent and both correct? [If only one question is allowed, then this last one if key.]

Answer (score 1):

Both usages are correct, note that rife is often used to refer to something, bad, unpleasant. *Rife with* is more idiomatic.

> [Rife](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/rife)  means “abundant” or “prevalent.” Rife can follow the word it’s describing, as in “corruption was rife during his administration.” ***More commonly, however, rife comes before the word it modifies, accompanied by the preposition with***, as in “the class was rife with yawns” or “her story was rife with inconsistencies.”

(Vocabulary.com)

***[Rife](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/rife)*** :

> ***if something bad or unpleasant is rife in a place***, it is very common there.
>   (synonym widespread)
>
> - *It is a country where corruption is rife.*
> - *Rumours are rife that he is going to resign*.
>
> ***rife (with something)*** full of something bad or unpleasant
>
> - *Los Angeles is rife with gossip about the stars' private lives*.

(OLD)